# Django DurationField default

Tags: python, django, timedelta, django-1.8

I want to pass default value into DurationField from django 1.8. According to documentation it should be datetime.timedelta

```
from datetime import timedelta
pause = DurationField(default=timedelta(minutes=20))
```

But on makemigrations it says:

```
ValueError: Cannot serialize: datetime.timedelta(0, 1200)
There are some values Django cannot serialize into migration files.
```

Ok. Maybe we should pass integer?

```
pause = DurationField(default=int(timedelta(minutes=20).total_seconds()))
```

or:

```
pause = DurationField(default=20*60)
```

makemigrations runs ok, but on object creation I see:

```
for obj in self.query.objs
  File "/home/web/django_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 920, in <listcomp>
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "/home/web/django_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 918, in <listcomp>
    ) for f in fields
  File "/home/web/django_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 710, in get_db_prep_save
    prepared=False)
  File "/home/web/django_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1683, in get_db_prep_value
    return value.total_seconds() * 1000000
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'
```

So it want timedelta?

Comment: I don't have a answer, this might be a bug. But see this ticket: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24445, where a core django developer says: "you should provide a timedelta value for your DurationField default value".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default should be a timedelta. This is a bug in Django and is set to be fixed in the 1.8.1 release.
See: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24566

So `pause = DurationField(default=timedelta(minutes=20))`
Should work with the 1.8.1 release.

Answer (score 1):

You mixed up the order of things slightly:

```
pause = DurationField(default=int(timedelta(minutes=20).total_seconds()))
```

As mentioned, integers don't have a `total_seconds()` attribute. Rather, it is an [instance method of `timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds).

Comment: sorry, mistake in qestion, I tried int(timedelta(minutes=20).total_seconds())