# Django: durationField default value

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-1.8

What's the right way to use Django's `DurationField`?

When I use `time_passed = models.DurationField(default=0)`:

- Migrations work
- Form defaults **don't** work (`'int' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'`)

When I use `time_passed = models.DurationField(default=timedelta())`:

- Migrations **don't** work (`ValueError: Cannot serialize: datetime.timedelta(0)`)
- Form defaults work

So what is the right way to use a default value on duration field or a workaround for this issue?

Comment: This might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29671903/django-durationfield-default

Comment: @EllaShar...You just linked to this exact question

Comment: @rnevius oops, edited.

Comment: @EllaShar I know but the question never got answer (the purposed answer doesn't work either). And I can't comment on it either.

Comment: this looks like a bug, you should report it. `django.db.migrations.writer.MigrationWriter.serialize` has a bunch of special cases for different data types, notably dates, datetime and time, so it seems like maybe `timedelta` should be in there too.  As a workaround you could try to make a subclass of `DurationField` and implement the [`deconstruct()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-model-fields/#field-deconstruction) ...this is already how it's done in Django's `EmailField`, `IPAddressField` and some others

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default should be a timedelta. This is a bug in Django and is set to be fixed in the 1.8.1 release.

See: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24566

So using default should be:

```py
from datetime import timedelta


time_passed = models.DurationField(default=timedelta)
```

Comment: You don't want to create a (mutable) instance of a timedelta object here, you only want to reference the class.  So instead of ``models.DurationField(default=timedelta())``, do ``models.DurationField(default=timedelta)``.  See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default

Comment: @TroyGrosfield And what is it exactly supposed to achieve with your suggestion? How could assigning `timedelta` fill the desired value at creation time if we dont provide arguments?

Comment: @DarkFranX if you call use timedelta() it will immediately execute and give you a value.  If you provide the function "timedelta" (no parens) instead, it will know it's a function and call it when needed which will give you a new instance of the object.  See django's doc that was provided above for more of an explanation.

Comment: @TroyGrosfield  What would be the parameters passed to `timedelta` in that case?

Comment: @DarkFranX It would be the equivalent of calling the method with no parameters.  So in this case "timedelta()".

Comment: Actually @TroyGrosfield's comment IS the correct answer, MatZeg's answer is NOT correct.

Answer (score 0):

MatZeg's [answer on this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29740876/7560156) shows that you can still pass in arguments as well:

```py
pause = DurationField(default=timedelta(minutes=20))
```